# 'Tag wiki edit' privileges discrepancy

Tags: discussion, privileges, tag-wiki

Is there any rationale behind the fact that it takes 5000 reputation points to be able to review tag-wiki edits but 20 000 to be able to edit directly tag-wikis without review, when in parallel, the post edits review and direct edit privileges are both obtained at the same milestone (i. e. 2000 reputation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag wikis see far less traffic and scrutiny. Editing a post bumps it up onto various pages, attracting a lot more visitors than a tag wiki edit ever does.

As such, you need to have a far higher trust level before you are allowed to edit tag wikis without review.

Comment: Meaning that there is a higher risk of vandalism staying unnoticed? Is it really reasonable to think a user with more than 5000 reputation will vandalize a wiki?

Comment: @plannapus: you'd be surprised. I can make 5k in under two weeks.

Comment: Ok, fair enough :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I doubt that a low reputation user with not much posts to get upvotes on to begin with would be able to get 5k in less than a month (and the effort would be a lot to begin with).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I'd get those 5k entirely on new answers. Yes, it'd be a lot of work, but it is certainly attainable.